# Multiple swipe recognizer in different components of controller ios

Tags: ios, ios8, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have an `UIViewController` with a default swipe recognizer to open/close the right side menu of my app(I am using `ECSlidingViewController` plug in). This swipe recognizer is set to the parent view of the controller.

Here is part of the code to detect the swipe to open the right side menu:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];}
```

Inside this `UIViewController` i have an `UIImageView`, i need to detect swipe to all directions (right,left,up,down). So far, i have set all swipes on the  `Storyboard` to `UIImageView`, but the app only detects the swipe of one component (the one in the parent view to open the right side menu or the one in the `UIImageView`), not both.

How can i make to detect swipe on both components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that happens is because your gesture recognizers on the image view are added during `initWithCoder`, and your other one is added during `viewDidLoad` which occurs after `initWithCoder`.

If you want both to take place, you'll need to implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`, otherwise iOS will just be greedy and take the latest gesture recognizer added if there is more than one for the same gesture (as you are seeing now).